# Way for Pathlib Path.rename() to create intermediate directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to move some files around on my filesystem. I'd like to use Python 3's Pathlib to do so, in particular, [Path.rename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename).

Say I want to move `Path('/a/b/c/d')` to `Path('/w/x/y/z')`.

```
Path('/a/b/c/d').rename(Path('/w/x/y/z'))
```

gives

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/a/b/c/d' -> '/w/x/y/z'
```

I can fix this with

```
os.makedirs(Path('/w/x/y', exist_ok=True)
Path('/a/b/c/d').rename(Path('/w/x/y/z'))
```

But that's less elegant than old school [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html), which has a method called [renames](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.renames) which does this for you. Is there a way to do this in Pathlib?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not ideal, but something like the following would work

```
from pathlib import Path

def ensure(path):
    path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    return path

Path('a/b/c/before.txt').rename(ensure(Path('x/y/z/moved.txt')))
```

`Pathlib.Path.mkdir` doesn't return anything, so it seems like some sort of wrapper like this is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

`pathlib.Path.mkdir()` is available:

```
newname = Path('/w/x/y/z')
newname.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
Path('/a/b/c/d').rename(newname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pathlib.mkdir offers the same parent-creation behavior

Pathlib.rename does not create parents, similar to how rename() does not create parents